# MySQL: how to sum up vaues of rows and sort the result?

Tags: mysql, sorting, sum

I'm looking for a SQL-statement that sums up some specific values and sorts the result. To be more clear: I have a table that consists of identifiers and values:

```
id     val
ab     10
ab     12
ab      3
cd     25
cd     10
ef      2
ef      7
```

Here all values for ab, cd and ef have to be summed up and ordered by result so that I get the following:

```
cd     35
ab     25
ef      9
```

So is there a SQL-statement that performs that task in one go?

Comment: You can learn more here: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Hello Elmi, do you want some more information about the GROUP BY instruction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id, SUM(val) as total
FROM your_table
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Comment: sum is a keyword, for alias i suggest using somethin that is not. (tho it will work ok in mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Use group function `sum`:

```
select id, sum(val) as val from my_table group by id order by 2 desc
```