# Search MySQL database table, order results by SUM

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

Similar to my question yesterday:

I have a database table 'sales_list'. In this is rows of sales records attributed to a users_sales_guild_id. I'd like to query the table and order results by the SUM of the 'sales_points' field by each user, highest points to lowest.

I found another question on SO that I thought would solve my issue - [MySQL: how to sum up vaues of rows and sort the result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073495/mysql-how-to-sum-up-vaues-of-rows-and-sort-the-result) - but it doesn't seem to hit the mark entirely.

I thought this query would do it, but alas no...

```
    $total_query = "SELECT users_sales_guild_new_id, SUM(sales_points) AS total_sales_points 
                    FROM sales_list
                    WHERE sales_entry_date BETWEEN '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-31 23:59:59' 
                    GROUP BY users_sales_guild_new_id
                    ORDER BY total_sales_points DESC";
```

This query returns only 1 record. rather than a selection of records ordered by the SUM of sales points by each user.

Your assistance is much welcomed.

Comment: You need to provide some sample dataset,desired resultset with your table definitions

Comment: Also please un-truncate your query

Comment: All records having sales_entry_date between 2013-10-01 00:00:00 and 2013-12-31 23:59:59' must be having the same users_sales_guild_new_id. That is why you are only seeing one row.

Answer (score 1):

Try this-> You can't pass the alias to order by.

```
$total_query = "SELECT users_sales_guild_new_id, SUM(sales_points) AS total_sales_points 
                    FROM sales_list
                    WHERE sales_entry_date BETWEEN '2013-10-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-12-31 23:59:59' 
                    GROUP BY users_sales_guild_new_id
                    ORDER BY SUM(sales_points) DESC";
```

Comment: Unfortunately the ORDER BY is causing problems @jitendra-yadav. If I remove it the query works fine. Thank you. I create an array later on during which I have been able to order by sales_points.